# Is there a rake task for backing up the data in your database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rake

Is there a rake task for backing up the data in your database?

I already have my schema backed up, but I want to make a backup of the data. It's a small MySQL database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below script is a simplified version taken from [eycap](http://github.com/engineyard/eycap/tree/master), specifically from [this file](http://github.com/engineyard/eycap/tree/master/lib/eycap/recipes/database.rb).

```
set :dbuser "user"
set :dbhost "host"
set :database "db"

namespace :db do
  desc "Get the database password from user"
  task :get_password do
    set(:dbpass) do
      Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask "Enter mysql password: "
    end
  end

  task :backup_name, :only => { :primary => true } do
    now = Time.now
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/db_backups"
    backup_time = [now.year,now.month,now.day,now.hour,now.min,now.sec].join('-')
    set :backup_file, "#{shared_path}/db_backups/#{database}-snapshot-#{backup_time}.sql"
  end

  desc "Dump database to backup file"
  task :dump, :roles => :db, :only => {:primary => true} do
    backup_name
    run "mysqldump --add-drop-table -u #{dbuser} -h #{dbhost} -p#{dbpass} #{database} | bzip2 -c > #{backup_file}.bz2"
  end
end
```

Edit: Yeah, I guess I missed the point that you were looking for a rake task and not a capistrano task, but I don't have a rake one on hand, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case people are still surfing for solutions, we currently use the ar_fixtures plugin to backup our db, well as part of the solution anyway.

It provides the rake `db:fixtures:dump` tasks. This spits out everythin in YAML into test/fixtures, so it can be loaded in again using `db:fixtures:load`.

We use this to backup before every feature push to production. We also used this when migrating from sqlite3 to Postgres - which is subtlety very useful as incompatibilities between SQL dialects are, for the most part, hidden.

All the best, D

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a rake task for backing up my MySQL db, but I did write a script in Ruby to do just that for my WordPress DB:

```
filename = 'wp-config.php'
def get_db_info(file)
  username = nil
  password = nil
  db_name = nil

  file.each { |line|
    if line =~ /'DB_(USER|PASSWORD|NAME)', '([[:alnum:]]*)'/
      if $1 == "USER"
        username = $2
      elsif $1 == "PASSWORD"
        password = $2
      elsif $1 == "NAME"
        db_name = $2
      end
    end
  }

  if username.nil? || password.nil? || db_name.nil?
    puts "[backup_db][bad] couldn't get all needed info"
    exit
  end

  return username, password, db_name
end

begin
  config_file = open("#{filename}")
rescue Errno::ENOENT
  puts "[backup_db][bad] File '#{filename}' didn't exist"
  exit
else
  puts "[backup_db][good] File '#{filename}' existed"
end

username, password, db_name = get_db_info(config_file)
sql_dump_info = `mysqldump --user=#{username} --password=#{password} #{dbname}`
puts sql_dump_info
```

You should be able to take this and do some mild pruning of it to put in your username/password/dbname to get it up and working for you. I put it in my crontab to run everyday as well, and it shouldn't be too much work to convert this to run as a rake task since it's already Ruby code (might be a good learning exercise as well).

Tell us how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

There are [a](http://code.google.com/p/ar-backup/) [few](http://topfunky.net/svn/shovel/backup.rake) [solutions](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4777) already on google. I am going to guess that you are using activerecord as your orm?

If you are running rails, then you can looks at the Rakefile that it uses for activerecord in \ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\rails-2.0.2-\lib\tasks\database.rake. That gave me a lot of information on how to extend the generic Rakefile.

You could take the capistrano tasks that [thelsdj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442/is-there-a-rake-task-for-backing-up-the-data-in-your-database#27448) provides, and add it to your rake file. Then modify it a bit so that it uses the activerecord connection to the database.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin out there called "mysql tasks", just google for it.  It's just a rakefile -- I've found it very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the  "--routines" parameter to mysqldump if you have any stored procs in your database so it backs them up too.

Answer (score 0):

There is my rake task to backup mysql, and rotate backups cyclically.

```
#encoding: utf-8
#require 'fileutils'

namespace :mls do
  desc 'Create of realty_dev database backup'

  task :backup => :environment do
    backup_max_records = 4
    datestamp = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
    backup_dir = File.join(Rails.root, ENV['DIR'] || 'backups', 'db')
    backup_file_name = "#{datestamp}_#{Rails.env}_dump.sql"
    backup_file_path = File.join(backup_dir, "#{backup_file_name}")
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(backup_dir)

    #database processing
    db_config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]
    system "mysqldump -u#{db_config['username']} -p#{db_config['password']} -i -c -q #{db_config['database']} > #{backup_file_path}"
    raise 'Unable to make DB backup!' if ($?.to_i > 0)

    # sql dump file compression
    system "gzip -9 #{backup_file_path}"

    # backup rotation
    dir = Dir.new(backup_dir)
    backup_all_records = dir.entries.sort[2..-1].reverse
    puts "Created backup: #{backup_file_name}.gz"
    #redundant records
    backup_del_records = backup_all_records[backup_max_records..-1] || []

    # backup deleting too old records
    for backup_del_record in backup_del_records
      FileUtils.rm_rf(File.join(backup_dir, backup_del_record))
    end

    puts "Deleted #{backup_del_records.length} old backups, #{backup_all_records.length - backup_del_records.length} backups available"
    puts "Backup passed"
  end
end

=begin
 run by this command: " rake db:backup RAILS_ENV="development" "
=end
```